# How to convert multiline string INPUT into a singlle line string?

Tags: python, string, input, multiline

I made bot that sends tracks discord channel and send me the messages every 24 hours. the message are like this:

Daily Quest announcement | click here to report a problem

Today's Daily Quest is:

n of random item 1 For 40-50 coins

n random item 2 for 10-20 coins    (n is between 1 to 200)

Today's Date:

May 25, 2023

Estimated Final Price:

50 coins

Price Prediction:

slowly Dropping

...

i dont really care about anything i just want to store the n of random item 1 and n of random item 2

The problem i encountered is that i can only acess string in line 1
if i do  `message.find("Today")` i get `-1` as a result

Ive tried getting rid of the \n by:

```
single_line = message.replace('\n', '')
```

or

```
message.strip("\n")
```

but nothing seems to work

It works perfectly on regular multiline strings

```
working_string = """ multiline
string
that
works
"""
```

but when i try to do

```
x = str(input("paste message")
```

it doesnt work

thank you for reading

Comment: `input` takes data up until new line. If you want to capture multiple lines, you need to call input multiple times.

Comment: `input()` returns a string, so `str(input())` is redundant.

Comment: Please provide the code that produces "message" variable.